# PHP - create a download script to avoid direct html links in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hyperlink, download

In my Wordpress plugin I create a file in a restricted folder.
How is possible to produce a download script to serve it as html not-direct link?

In other words I want the real path of the file not to be showed on the "href" of a link, but to be detected and added from a backend function.

The frontend html would be something like:

```
<a href="/download?fn=filename.ext">Download my file</a>
```

But the teal file path/name would be "/restriced-dir/filename.ext".

Comment: When you clicked to create this post the button said "Ask Question". But "I want" or "I need" is not a question, or a problem statement. And "how to" is a bit too vague. This site is not a free write-my-code, design-my-solution or do-my-thinking service. We'll _help_ you with your attempt to solve your problem / implement your requirement. What research have you done? What code have you tried? What exact issue(s) are you facing? Please read [ask] for further guidance on how to ask a useful question. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. thanks. Just trying to save time to others facing the same problem.

Comment: It wasn't obvious you intended to answer it yourself, and that doesn't remove the need to ask a decent question in case others want to answer to too. "Is it possible to" isn't much better too...I doubt you want "yes" as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I solved the problem by myself.
In my plugin I've created a "dirty" custom endpoint to serve any existing file from a restricted folder (in a non-public location).

```
define( 'RESTRICTED_DOWNLOAD_DIR', '/restricted-dir/' );
        
add_action( 'parse_request', 'parse_request_endpoint' );
    
    function parse_request_endpoint($wp) {
            
            //endpoint url
            $endpoint="download";
            if ( $endpoint == $wp->request ) {
                @$fn=sanitize_file_name($_GET["fn"]);//As from suggestion for security reasons
                $filename=RESTRICTED_DOWNLOAD_DIR.$fn;
                if(is_file($filename)){
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
                readfile($filename);
                unlink($filename);//If served just once
                exit;
                }
            }
        }
```

Then I can use a function for the html output ant call it from code or shortcode:

```
function my_file_link(){
   $filename="myfile.ext";//this file must exist in RESTRICTED_DOWNLOAD_DIR
   $html="<a href=\"/download?fn=$filename\">Download my file</a>";
   return $html;
}
```

This way if the file is found gets downloaded but if the url is called without the right parameter Wordpress will show a 404 page. The solution could be improved adding a blocking logic in download endpoint.

Comment: You created yourself a massive security hole there. It is absolutely easy to break out of your "restricted" directory, by passing a value for the `fn` parameter that starts with one or multiple `../`

Comment: Modified sanitizing the filename. Thanks.